# alert box for a calculation field

Tags: html, alert

How can I have an alert box pop up if the number in the `Answer_2` field is greater than 10, or less than -10?

[Here's my example](http://jsfiddle.net/qvDFY/15/)

Javascript:

```
    function CalculateIMSUB(Atext, Btext, form, val)
    {
    var A = eval(Atext);
    var B = eval(Btext);
    if (isNaN(A)) A = 0;
    if (isNaN(B)) B = 0;
    var answer = A - B;
    form.Answer.value = answer;    

    var diff = answer - val;
    if (diff == 0)
    form.Answer_2.value = 'ok';
    else if (diff < 0)
    form.Answer_2.value = diff;
    else
    form.Answer_2.value = '+' + diff;
    }

    function calculateAll() {
    var forms = document.getElementsByTagName("form");
    for(var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++ ) {
    CalculateIMSUB(forms[i].input_A.value, forms[i].input_B.value,forms[i], 96)                
    }
    }
```

HTML:

```
    <FORM NAME="Calculator" METHOD="GET">
    <P><INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="input_A" SIZE=10><INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="input_B" SIZE=10>  
    <INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="+" name="subtractbutton" onclick="CalculateIMSUB
    (this.form.input_A.value, this.form.input_B.value, this.form, 96)">
    <INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="Answer" SIZE=12><tt>96</tt><INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="Answer_2"   
    SIZE=4></P></form>
    <input type="button" onclick="calculateAll()" value="Master calculation" />
```

Thanks very much in advance

Comment: Please make your question complete by including relevant, formatted code inline (don't just link to jsfiddle.net).

Comment: The reason we want to see your code, instead of a link to it, is, WHEN the link breaks, your question will become useless.

Comment: Charlies Tian thank you for pointing the acceptance rating out, I have only used this website only a handful of times and was oblivous to the notion of the acceptance rating. I believe I have made the necessary changes to my question so that if anyone can help that would be fantastic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, only thing you need to do is this, under where you calculate `var diff`

```
if(diff < -10 || diff > 10)
    alert("diff is more Tham 10");
```